# How to return HTML response from action to component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

```
I have a GET url which returns HTML data as its response. I am able to see the html response in networks tab in chrome but the same is not returned to my component. 

Adding code snippet for my implementation.
```

Component Code :

```
import { getResult } from 'REDUX/actions/appConfigActions';

componentDidMount() {
  const { actions: { getResult }} = this.props;
  getResult();
}

render() {
const { searchResult } = this.props;
console.log('searchResult  >>', searchResult);
return (
   <div>{searchResult}</div>
)
}
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 searchResult: state.appConfig.searchResult,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 actions: bindActionCreators({ getResult }, dispatch),
});
```

Action Code :
 I tried setting header while calling the action still didn't work. We are using **superagent-defaults** for making request. I have been referring to [SuperAgent link](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) for my implementation.

```
export const getResult = () => {
const _url = 'someworkingurl';
  return (dispatch) => {
    req.get(`${_url}`)
       .type('text/html;charset=utf-8')
       .set('content-type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')
       .set('Accept', 'text/html')
      .set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
      .accept('text/html;charset=utf-8')
     .then(({ body  }) => dispatch({
          type: 'result',
          payload: body
        }))
        .catch(err => dispatch(getError));
  };
};
```

Comment: are you able to console log `body` before calling dispatch?

Comment: Yes .. its showing as null in the component

Comment: Just for reference, here "req" is a superagent-defaults object

Comment: can you provide all involved code store/component?

Comment: @Simon Updated my question with code snippet

Comment: Use code as below to get html response  :
.then(({ text  }) => dispatch({
          type: 'result',
          payload: text
        }))